# For loop returning incorrect syntax

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I recently viewed this question's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18017189/2371039) and basically copy and pasted it into my own batch file, but made some edits.  When I ran it, the file returned incorrect syntax, and with some debug, found it was hanging on the first for loop.  I have not done anything with for loops in batch before, and therefore, do not know the proper syntax for it.

CODE:

```
::@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo setlocal
pause
cd /d "%CD%"
echo cd
pause
for %%a in (*-*.*) do (
    echo for1
    pause
    for /f "delims=-" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "f=%%b"
        if /i "%%~xa"==".pdf" (
            md "%CD%/pdf/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/pdf/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".png" (
            md "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".jpg" (
            md "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".jpeg" (
            md "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".txt" (
            md "%CD%/txt/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/txt/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".html" (
            md "%CD%/html/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/html/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".gif" (
            md "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/images/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".exe" (
            md "%CD%/exe/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/exe/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".xml" (
            md "%CD%/html/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/html/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".wav" (
            md "%CD%/videos/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/videos/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".mov" (
            md "%CD%/videos/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/videos/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".mp4" (
            md "%CD%/videos/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/videos/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".ogg" (
            md "%CD%/music/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/music/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else if /i "%%~xa"==".mp3" (
            md "%CD%/music/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/music/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        ) else
            md "%CD%/other/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
            move "%%a" "%CD%/other/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
        )
    )
)
```

If this is a n00b mistake I have in it, please explain it so I will not be a n00b about it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an opening parenthesis to the last `ELSE`, as you try to close it ...

And it's not allowed to use ELSE without a following command or code block.

```
...
   ) else (
       md "%CD%/other/!f:~0,-1!" 2>nul
       move "%%a" "%CD%/other/!f:~0,-1!" >nul
   )
...
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I now have the batch file working and sorting files.  This just saved me hours of work.  Now only if an AI could read my mind on which files to keep...xD